# Custom row elements in ListFragment are displaying incorrectly after scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` containing a list of `Earthquake` objects that populates using a custom `ArrayAdapter`. Each element is either 'highlighted' or not, depending on whether the magnitude of the earthquake is above a certain value. The problem is that after scrolling, the 'highlighted' row colors will be applied to other rows. I suspect this is to do with the caching used in the `ListView`. How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is the `getView` method of my `EarthquakeArrayAdapter` class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }

    Earthquake quake = mQuakes.get(position);
    if (quake != null) {
        TextView itemView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.magnitude);
        if (itemView != null) {
            itemView.setText(quake.getFormattedMagnitude());
            if (quake.getRoundedMagnitude() >= mMinHighlight)
                itemView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    // Set other views in the layout, no problems here...
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

And here is my `row.xml` layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/magnitude"
       style="@style/ListFont.Magnitude" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            style="@style/ListFont.NonMagnitude"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            style="@style/ListFont.NonMagnitude"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've watched [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) video on the `ListView` widget and I'm considering doing what Adam Powell suggests at the end - dynamically populating & expanding a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` and simply using that. My data is presently bounded between 0 and 30 items (I haven't yet tested this so don't know what the performance difference is likely to be). However, those bounds may not always stay the same - so I'd like to solve this, if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by highlight you mean setting the color on the magnitude `TextView` then you simply have to revert any changes if the magnitude isn't the required one:

```
if (quake.getRoundedMagnitude() >= mMinHighlight) {
     itemView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
} else {
     itemView.setTextColor(/*the default color*/);
}
```

Comment: Well that's an embarrassingly simple solution. Why did my original code work on the first draw, and then change when the items scroll, though? I would've thought that not setting the text color (ie, leaving it as the default) would've been equivalent to explicitly specifying the default color.

Comment: @adamsp You code work at first because there is no recycled row involved. As soon as you scroll the `ListView`, it could recycle some of the previous rows to reuse them to improve performance. For example the first position is RED and you scroll the list. When it's time to show a new row the `ListView` could reuse the first row and show it as the new row(with the red color still present because you don't revert it). So you should always put the row in the default state(ex. no RED color) if the current row doesn't fulfill some condition.